# html5 canvas drawImage without alpha

Tags: html, canvas, transparency, drawimage

I'd like to know if it possible to not use the alpha channel but keeping transparency.
What I need is to draw or not draw pixel (of my png file) depending on the alpha value

If alpha channel > 128 draw Pixel
else don't draw pixel !

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to go about that.

One way is just to draw the image, then call `getImageData`

Go over every pixel in the image data, and if the alpha component is <= 128, make that pixel fully transparent.

Then put the modified imageData back with `putImageData`

This is from memory so I might have missed something:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,picwidth, picheight);
var pixels = imageData.data;
var numPixels = pixels.length;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    if (pixels[i*4+3] <= 128) pixels[i*4+3] = 0;
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: well, in fact this is not what i'm looking for. A'd like to modify the image and not the canvas. I want to make a pre traitment before blitting the image...

Comment: So you must do the exact same thing as above, except draw the image to an in-memory canvas. So use `document.createElement('canvas')` to make a new canvas, draw the image to it, apply the above operations, and then draw *that* canvas to your normal canvas. (`ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0)`)

Comment: ah ok. thank's. I'll try. but that mean that a canvas can have a alpha channel. I'll try... That will be great if it's work.

Comment: All canvases have an alpha channel. In fact the default canvas is transparent black (aka rgba(0,0,0,0))